# Pratition rectangle into smaller ones containig exactly 1 point, maximize wastelands area

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, mathematical-optimization

Given a rectangle R containing P points, orthogonal with axes, points are natural numbers.

**Parcel is a rectangle which:**

- is totally inside R
- sides are orthgonal with axes
- contains exactly ONE point inside
- its sides must be adjacent to sides of R or contain point(s) from P

Find an algorithm to find <s>all possible</s> parcels inside R, so their total area is minimal (maximize wastelands area).

*Example: One of many ways of division, 5 points(*), 2 parcels*

```
    R
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                   |                   |       |
|                   |                   |   *   |
|                   *                   |       |
|                   |                   *       |
|                   |               *   |       |
|                   |                   |       |
|                   |                   |       |
|                   |-----------*-------|       |
|    wastelands                         |       |
|                                       |       |
|                                       |       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

Firstly, lets skip optimizing(max/min). Is there any good way to partition a rectangle?

### Edit

It looks like it might be NP-hard. I got some feedback from initiator of this problem and finding **all** possible parcels is pointless.
I think the only way is to use some heuristic (e.g. finding biggest parcels or parcels which sides contain most of points) and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a backtracking and exponentially hard method for starters. You pick your points in some order and each time do either of the following:

1- Decide to pass a vertical line
2- Decide to pass a horizontal line 
3- Decide to ignore

Until you end-up with 3^n different cases.

For your own application, you could think of applying some bounding conditions at each iteration, e.g., verify if you have ended up with a parcel with no point inside, then backtrack.

Comment: I have noticed that in some cases when there are only 2 or 3 points left possibilities are limited. Maybe finding **all** possible parcels isn't the way, but to find **any** of them with some decomposition?

Comment: Here is my thought on this. Let's assume you are given these "n" points and want to find a "parcel" partitioning which is also a good parcel, i.e., exactly one point left in each parcel. How fast can you do it? One way is to model the problem as a SAT problem by defining boolean variables on whether or not a vertical or horizontal line passes the point (e.g., vi and hi for point i). This modeling however, leads to k-SAT (k > 3) and no efficient algorithms solves it. I am trying to understand whether or not a faster algorithm exists.

Comment: I am thinking about using 2-d tree and range searches. Firstly make 2-d tree; 1. get a start point, find its nearest neighbors (a point or rectangle's R side) on North, E, S, W (we've a parcel); 2. mark these neighbors as visited; 3. continue finding neighbors of not visited points ; 4. Repeat 1-3 for every point (change starting points). I'm wondering whether it is efficient/not too complex and possible way to find some partitions of rectangle R. It will not give us all possible, but most of them. Is it worth trying?

Comment: You are visiting points this way, which is something like breadth first search when you assume an edge based on distance. Each point will have edges to (at most) 4 other points. E.g., (x, y) has an edge to (x', y') and vice versa iff (x', y') = argmin_(all points (u, v): u > x) (u - x). The same thing for "y" coordinate. However, the question is how would you decide on whether or not passing a line through a point. Could this problem be NP-hard?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force is to find for each point all possible rectangles that contain that point (in inside) and solve [exact cover set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem) on collection of all rectangles.

To find all rectangles that contain given point is 'relatively' simple :-)

Start with a rectangle that have maximal one side. E.g. for point (a,b) rectangle with maximal y side is one that has vertical boundaries on points which x coordinate is nearest to a (from both sides) and horizontal boundaries are on R. That is not case if there is other point(s) with x coordinate equal a, but that will only move horizontal boundary to the nearest point in y direction.

Next rectangle has to have smaller y side, that means that boundary point (B) that was used for vertical boundary in shorter rectangle is used for horizontal boundary. Point for vertical boundary is choose from point from same side as B to support rectangle constraints (create rectangle, no other point in rectangle area.)