# Algorithm - Points and parcels

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, rectangles

I'm new here so I hope you won't lose your patience too quickly :D I have an algorithmic problem which I'm not sure how to solve. I have looked for something similar on stack overflow and there was even someone who posted a question resembling mine very much, but few minor details made it impossible to adapt the solution here.

I have a rectangular area in the coordinate system with some points within. I want to create "parcels" based on the points. A parcel is a rectangle which has exactly one point inside. The sides of a parcel can be either included in the borders of the area or they can be drawn somewhere within the area provided that each of them strikes through at least one point. Some examples of correct parcels:

[image]

The problem is, I have to return **the minimum number of parcels which would make all points "occupied"**. So in the above case I think one of the solutions could be:

[image]

So **the correct answer would be 3**.

I think it is worth starting from creating a parcel "in the corner" because then the remaining points are scattered in only two directions. If we start from creating a parcel in the middle of the set, then chances are points are scattered everywhere, in each direction, and since parcels can't cross each other, we would have to use more parcels.

The problem is, I don't know if my reasoning is right and I can't think of a proper algorithm based on it. Do you guys find it reasonable or is there a completely different method I didn't think of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362658/pratition-rectangle-into-smaller-ones-containig-exactly-1-point-maximize-wastel

Comment: Thanks, the conditions are similar, but the question is quite different.